# Why does my django rest-framework pagination does not work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I have a Django Restframework project.
Here is my view:

```
class JobView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = [...]
    ordering_fields = ['jobId']
    ordering = ['-jobId']
    filterset_fields = ['jobId', 'status']
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

and my pagination class:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    page_size = 1
```

The view is registerd in a router:

```
router.register(r'jobs', JobView)
```

The problem is, it does not paginate at all. It just ignores the pagination_class attribute.

I also tried:

```
class JobView(generics.ListAPIView)
```

And registered the view without the router. But the problem is the same. It does not paginate and just returns a json list with all jobs.

How can achieve pagination in this view without defining it for the project in settings.py globally?

Comment: What if you make a request to the `'jobs/?limit=2&offset=1'` page?

Comment: It magically works. At first I defined it globally in settings.py and in this case it paginated already without ?limit=2&offset=1
Thank you!

Comment: @EinEsellerEniE: likely with the `LimitOffsetPagination`, perhaps you should use `PageNumberPagination`?

Comment: The problem was I tried PageNumberPagination at first and it changed the output imideatly. I expedted LimitOffsetPagination to do the same. But in that case I had to use 'jobs/?limit=2&offset=1'.
For my usecase I need LimitOffsetPagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set a `default_limit` and call `/jobs`, it will display the result like normal. In case of `LimitOffsetPagination`, you need to either specify the limit and the offset in the request or specify the `default_limit` to see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `StandardResultsSetPagination` inherit from the correct pagination style? [LimitOffsetPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination) does not limit the output by default (aside from the `PAGE_SIZE` setting) and requires query parameters to set the limit. It also does not have a `page_size` class attribute, contrary to [PageNumberPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination).

Comment: The problem was I tried PageNumberPagination at first and it changed the output imideatly. I expedted LimitOffsetPagination to do the same. But in that case I had to use 'jobs/?limit=2&offset=1' to see a difference. For my usecase I need LimitOffsetPagination.

Comment: In that case you should be able to replace the `page_size` class attribute by [`default_limit`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#configuration_1). You might also want to have a look at `max_limit` for your use-case.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace your pagination class with the below code

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

Comment: They asked for a way to enable pagination that does not rely on Django settings, see the last paragraph.

Comment: Check my edited answer.